# When using javascript in pdf its not working in all browsers

Tags: itext

When inject javascript in file and give that reference in pdf its not working in all browser using itextsharp using pdfstamper..

```
function Signature1() {
  this.getField('BtnSignature').display = display.hidden;
  this.getField('Text1').display = display.visible;
  var cResponse=app.response({cQuestion:'Enter your Name',cTitle:'SIGNATURE'});
if(cResponse==null)
{app.alert('please enter name');cResponse=0;}
else
{this.getField('Text1').value=cResponse;this.getField('BtnSignature1').setFocus();} 
}
```

code side

```
Rectangle rect;
            rect = new Rectangle(pos.Left, pos.Bottom, pos.Right, pos.Top);
            PushbuttonField button = new PushbuttonField(pdfStamper.Writer, rect, "BtnSignature");
            button.BackgroundColor = new GrayColor(0.75f);
            button.BorderColor = GrayColor.GRAYBLACK;
            button.BorderWidth = 1;
            button.BorderStyle = PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_BEVELED;
            button.TextColor = GrayColor.GRAYBLACK;
            button.FontSize = 9;
            button.Text = "Sign Here";
            button.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_LEFT_LABEL_RIGHT;
            button.ScaleIcon = PushbuttonField.SCALE_ICON_ALWAYS;
            button.ProportionalIcon = true;
            button.IconHorizontalAdjustment = 0;
            button.Visibility = PushbuttonField.VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT;
            field = button.Field;

            //string strJava = string.Empty;
            //strJava = "this.getField('BtnSignature').display = display.hidden;";
            //strJava += "this.getField('Text1').display = display.visible;var cResponse=app.response({cQuestion:'Enter your Name',cTitle:'SIGNATURE'});if(cResponse==null){app.alert('please enter name');cResponse=0;}else{this.getField('Text1').value=cResponse;this.getField('BtnSignature1').setFocus();}";
            field.Action = PdfAction.JavaScript("this.Signature1()", pdfStamper.Writer);
```

Comment: Not all PDF viewers support JavaScript, and those that do, don't necessarily support the full PDF JavaScript object model. And even browsers that do support JavaScript usually can be configured to switch off that support.

Comment: Means javascript is not work in pdf viewer browser like chrome,mozila,etc,But my requirement to show in browser is there any other way?

Comment: Well, first off all become clear which pdf viewers exactly need to be supported. If any of them don't support Javascript, design the PDF without. Also, become clear whether pdf viewers with Javascript support switched off need to be supported. If yes, design your pdf without Javascript.